# Firestore query List map object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone help me to query the list of map object in the collection? Please find sample document below
[see my sample document from firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH19n.png)

In above the image I want to fetch the GROUP collection based on personId which is basically List type.

Searching for solution android. Please advise

Comment: Can you please add a more detailed database structure and indicate the exact values that you want to get?

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether its an optimal way of performing a query in Firestore but i only found this way. You can query a map but you will need both the personId as well as personName

```
Future<void> memberList() async {
      List<Map> personList= new List<Map>();
      Map<String, dynamic> personData = new Map<String,dynamic>();
      personData ["personId"] = pid;
      personData ['personName'] = pname;
      personList.add(personData);
      QuerySnapshot query;
      query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Group')
     .where('groupMembers',arrayContainsAny: personList).get();
 }
```