# React-Native Firestore how to query array of objects and indexing

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an application using react-native. In my document structure, I have an array of objects which is much like this:

[image: Quoted from another post]

There is a very similar so discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343063/firestore-query-list-map-object) but not answered. Plus, I have additional questions.

I would like to know 4 things:

1. What indexes would be created for my queries automatically?
2. How can I query for groups that include a specific user?
3. Can I/should I create my own indexes to support this specific query?
4. If I want to make certain documents accessible to certain groups of people, how would I achieve this?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm interested in the last question specifically. I believe the answer to the first three are "None, [`.where("groupId", "==", docSnapshot.data().groupId)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), and "No", though I'm not certain that the first and third answer are correct.